# Terraform conditionals - if variable does not exist

Tags: terraform

I have the following condition:

```
resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_application" "service" {
  appversion_lifecycle {
    service_role          = "service-role"
    delete_source_from_s3 = "${var.env == "production" ?   false : true}"
  }
}
```

If `var.env` is set to `production`, I get the result I want.

However if `var.env` is not defined, `terraform plan` will fail because the variable was never defined.
How can I get this to work, without ever having to define that variable?

Comment: Do you mean without having to define a default value?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Seems these days you can also use `try` to check if something is set.

```
try(var.env, false)
```

After that your code will work since `var.env` is now defined with the value `false` even if `var.env` was never defined somewhere.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/try.html

Comment: This answer helped me out on my current project, creating a module for security groups & rules. I haven't gotten it fully working yet but this allows for me to set values to null when I'm flattening a list built out of a complex map.

Comment: had no idea this existed. amazing. thanks so much.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 37):

if you are using Terraform 0.12 or later, you can assign the special value null to an argument to mark it as "unset".

```
variable "env" {
    type = "string"
    default = null
}
```

You can't just leave it blank, not with the current versions.

Comment: but how to check it later that it is unset ?

Comment: Apparently you can check `var.env == null`

Answer (score 19):

You can have the default of the variable set to an empty string:

```
variable "env" {
  description = "Env where the module is deployed."
  type        = string
  default     = ""
}
```

Once that is done, your check `var.env == "production"` will produce `false` and the argument delete_source_from_s3 will be assigned to the value `true`.

Side note, there is no need for interpolation in the statement,

`"${var.env == "production" ?   false : true}"`

just go with,

```
delete_source_from_s3 = var.env == "production" ? false : true
```

https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/how-do-write-an-if-else-block/2563

Comment: `delete_source_from_s3 = var.env != "production"` is the same