# Assign provided value if variable/local does not exist

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I would like to set the `disk_size` doing something like the following:

```
resource "google_compute_disk" "terraform-additional-persistent-disk" {
    name = "terraform-additional-persistent-disk"
    zone = local.zone
    type = local.default_disk_type
    size = exists(local.default_disk_size) ? local.default_disk_size : 50
    image = local.default_ubuntu_image
    labels = {
        created_by = "terraform"
    }
}
```

However, I have not been able to find a `exists` function in Terraform. The main aim is to take the value of a variable/local if it exists and, if it has not been declared anywhere, then take the value I pass as second argument.

I have been checking other questions like [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53200585/terraform-conditionals-if-variable-does-not-exist) but neither `can` nor `try` function are helping me achieve my goal. I will always get either `A local value with the name "default_disk_size" has not been declared` or `An input variable with the name "default_disk_size" has not been declared` (depending on whether I use a non-existing `local` or `var`).

I have even tried to run the following, but it will always raise an exception if the variable/local has not been set. Is there a way of achieving this without explicitly declaring the variable with a default value of `null`/`""`?

Thanks!

```
resource "google_compute_disk" "terraform-additional-persistent-disk" {
    name = "terraform-additional-persistent-disk"
    zone = local.zone
    type = local.default_disk_type
    size = merge({sizee=50}, {sizee = local.default_disk_sizee})["sizee"]
    image = local.default_ubuntu_image
    labels = {
        created_by = "terraform"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're coming at this with the idea that input variables and locals may or may not exist at the time this resource is created, like they are system environment variables or something. However in Terraform, those things have to be explicitly declared in one of the .tf files in the same folder as the file your `google_compute_disk.terraform-additional-persistent-disk` is declared.

There would be no way in Terraform's syntax to have either local or input variables appear dynamically at runtime, they have to be declared ahead of time in your code. They will always exist.

If you want to allow someone using your Terraform code the option of passing in a variable or not, you have to explicitly declare the variable, and give it a default value. Then the person using your Terraform code can optionally override that default value. Like this:

```
variable "disk_size" {
  type        = number
  default     = 50
  description = "The size of the additional persistent disk"
}

resource "google_compute_disk" "terraform-additional-persistent-disk" {
    name = "terraform-additional-persistent-disk"
    zone = local.zone
    type = local.default_disk_type
    size = var.disk_size
    image = local.default_ubuntu_image
    labels = {
        created_by = "terraform"
    }
}
```

Then when someone uses your Terraform code, if they don't specify a value for the `disk_size` input variable, the default of `50` will be used, but if they do specify something, then the value they specified will be used.

Comment: Fair enough thanks. My main reasoning was to take the value defined by someone else (as in, an organisation policy that needs to be followed) and, if there is not a restriction for a particular value, use the value I define. I believe the closest I can get to this is using a map called `default_vars` in both locals and variables files and, depending on the order used in the merge, I will give more priority to either the variables from the main module or to my local variables. Something more complex can be done as well with `lookup` in case the variable has as default value `""`

Comment: The entire `merge()` thing you are doing in the code in your question just seems like a ton of hoops to jump through to just set a default value that can be overridden, when there is already a mechanism built into Terraform for defining a default value that can be overridden (which I show in my answer). I highly recommend you look at the source code for some of the official AWS and GCP Terraform modules out there, to see how they are building Terraform modules that can be reused by so many people.